# use setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener instead of SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE make a problem with padding

Tags: android, kotlin

this is my original screen
[image]

I used this line to make the view scroll when keyboard appears

```
requireActivity().window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
```

but it's depreciated in API level 30

so i used this code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            getWindow().setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
            ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(getWindow().getDecorView(), (v, insets) -> {
                int imeHeight = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom;
                root.setPadding(0, 0, 0, imeHeight);
                return insets;
            });
        }
```

in My Activity
but there's a padding in the top of the screen and can't remove it

### [image]

so i removed it from activity and added this in the fragment

```
requireActivity().window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
binding.root.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { _, windowInsets ->
            val imeHeight = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.ime()).bottom
            binding.root.setPadding(0, 0, 0, imeHeight)
        
        windowInsets
    }
```

but the layout become behind the status bar and the bottom bar
[image]

so what should i do now ?

i need the view to scroll when keyboard appears and make the layout still appear as the original image, not behind status bar and bottom bar, and without this strange padding in top of screen